# Finding the molarity of the combination of two solution reacting with each other

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions, concentration

I have a question that gives two concentrations and asks for the mass of $\ce{HCl}$ formed by the reaction.

$$\ce{H2SO4 + NaCl ->Na2SO4 + HCl}$$

I have two concentrations:

$\pu{250 mL}$ of $\pu{4.00 M}$ $\ce{H2SO4}$, and $\pu{250 mL}$ of $\pu{1.00 M}$ $\ce{NaCl}$.

Here is the balanced reaction equation:

$$\ce{H2SO4 + 2NaCl ->Na2SO4 + 2HCl}$$

I know how to find the mass once I find the moles, molecular weights and then grams by multiplying the two.

However, how do I add those two concentrations? I assume the mixture will be at least $\pu{500 mL}$, but how do I add the molarity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your working equation is correct.
$$\ce{H2SO4 + 2NaCl ->Na2SO4 + 2HCl}$$

- Find the amount of substance of protons of each solution via $n=c\cdot V$.

> $n(\ce{H+})=2~\mathrm{mol}$, $n(\ce{Cl-})=0.25~\mathrm{mol}$

- What is the limiting agent?

> Chlorine

- How many moles of hydrogen chloride can only be formed?

> $n(\ce{HCl})=0.25~\mathrm{mol}$

- Calculate the mass of hydrogen chloride via $m = n\cdot M$

> $M(\ce{HCl})=36.5~\mathrm{g/mol}$, $m(\ce{HCl})=9.1~\mathrm{g}$

Comment: Martin, you are a formatting genius.

Comment: @Dissenter As a child I loved playing in a sandbox... so I enjoy that now and again too: [Check this out!](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111/formatting-sandbox-please-test-stuff-here)

Answer (score 0):

You're right; you can't directly add the two concentrations since these concentrations are specific to a certain volume of solvent.

If you want to recalculate concentrations of each system component in a combined solution, you need to find the moles of each system component in this combined solution, and then divide by the *total solution volume*.

Comment: So does that become 500mL of 2.500 M solution?

Comment: That is not quite correct, as you have a limiting agent present.